# How can you change the style of DetailsView Edit and Delete links?

Tags: asp.net

I know that you can change the style of the DetailsView CommandRowStyle, but what if I want to change the style of the actual Edit and Delete links? Can you access those?

I'd rather not use images, and I'd like to have my Edit and Delete links match the linkbutton CSS I've already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the ControlStyle-CSSClass property.  I didn't realize that was available, since I was looking for CSSClass like other controls use.

Thanks @FlopScientist for the help

Answer (score 2):

Two methods:

```
<asp:GridView ...cut...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="True">
             <!-- CSS classes on td -->
             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="command_field" />
             <!-- CSS classes on buttons -->
             <ControlStyle CssClass="button_style default_colour small_size" />
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Or

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="True"
     ControlStyle-CssClass="button_style" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Some options you can try to see which one is best are:

1.) Use `CommandField` inside your `<fields>` tag
This way you can display buttons instead of links for your Insert, Delete ... operations.

```
    <Fields>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ... />
    </Fields>
```

Note that `<asp:CommandField>` does not has any `CSSClass` property.

2.) you can use `TemplateField`. Inside this put any button, linkbutton etc as per your needs and specify `CSSClass` property so that you can customize it further with CSS styles. Refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx)

```
<asp:templatefield>
   <itemtemplate>
       <asp:Button id="NewRecordbtn" CssClass="ClassNewButton"
            CommandName="Insert"
            runat="server"/> 
       <asp:LinkButton id="DeleteButton" CSSClass="ClassDelButton"
            CommandName="Delete"
            runat="server"/>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

Hope you get the idea atleast.

However, please note that once you specify `<ItemTemplate>`, you should also specify `<InsertItemTemplate>` and `<EditItemTemplate>` as the case may be. Additionally refer [this link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t777932-custom-button-link-in-detailsview-commandfield-section.html) that portrays a similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below code line, it works for me nice.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ControlStyle-CssClass="fas fa-edit" />
```